# Skyrim Teleportation

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started playing Skyrim and I'm, all the time, dropping stuff I can't carry.
In other RPGs, I would teleport to town and sell stuff.
While I can Fast Travel to town, I have to run all the way back (including traps and enemies).

Is there a way to quickly get back to where I left?
I assume I can do it with mods, but I want to stick to vanilla for now.

Comment: You can use the `CenterOnCell` or `COC` console command to teleport yourself somewhere if you really want. Pretty cheaty though...and only works if you can access the console.

Comment: If you don't want to cheat/use console commands... no, there's no way. Managing your inventory space is a big part of the game.

Comment: Maybe that adds to the realism, but I miss Titan Quest's portal stone.

Comment: Minor point regarding the title; it's "Fast Travel" (as mentioned in the body of the question), not teleportation. Although out-of-game it's instant (depending on load times), in-game time does pass.

Comment: I decided that I wasting silly amounts of time managing what I could and couldn't carry, that could be spent better enjoying the game. So I launched the console (PC version) and increased my max carry weight to 10,000. Now I can focus on the stuff I enjoy rather than carrying lots!

Comment: There's a trick I would do in Oblivion and I believe also Skyrim (it's been awhile since I've played) where I would pick up the item with my character (the same way you would drag an item on screen, dragging a dead body etc) whatever button it is for that. You'll see the item 'hovering' in front of you, basically just run with this item hovering in front of you until you reach a merchant and then sell whatever you wish to sell.

Comment: I don't know if they patched this exploit with the recent updates to the game, but you used to be able to drop items on the ground, and command your follower to pick them up (they would do so without caring about how much they already were carrying).  It's a pain to do it with tons of smaller items, because it's rather slow, but it's an option. IIRC, you could also put the items in a container and command them to loot it, but then it tended to mark everything as stolen.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No.

Managing your inventory and carry weight is one of the primary gameplay mechanics of Skyrim.

One thing Skyrim has done to make this easier compared to previous entries in the series are convenient exits at the end of dungeons. Many dungeons are basically circles, where the last room is actually right next to the entrance. If you're stopping halfway through the dungeon and turning around to take stuff back to town, you're doing it wrong.

Instead, realize that you don't need to, and *shouldn't*, pick up everything. Many players who are new to this series and similar games make the mistake of picking up everything. Most of it is just junk for atmosphere. Another mistake is paying too much attention to the gross value of an item, while ignoring its weight.

Penny Arcade has even created [a comic commenting on this behavior](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14/thulsa-broom):

[image]

When you see an item, consider its value per pound. Iron Armor is worth 125 gold, but weighs 30 pounds. That's just over 4 gold per pound. Alto Wine is only worth 12 gold, but it only weighs 0.5 pounds. That's 24 gold per pound. This means that Alto Wine is worth almost six times as much as Iron Armor. Pick up the wine, not the armor.

I usually use a rule of thumb of picking up things worth 10 or more gold per pound for most of the game, just because it's easy to calculate and tends to work out. If you happen to get full, drop some heavy stuff and keep going. Once you get to the end of the dungeon, it's usually easy to exit quickly and fast travel back to town.

**Increasing Carry Weight**

If you *really*, *really* want to grab everything, there are things you can do to improve your carry weight. Also note that you only need to be unencumbered when you initiate fast travel, so a very temporary increase like you might get from a potion is enough to get you from point A to point B.

Increasing your stamina increases your carry weight, there's [a standing stone that increases your carry weight](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Steed_Stone_(Skyrim)), and your followers can carry things for you. There are also perks that reduce or nullify the weight of worn armor, and potions that temporarily increase carry weight.

Your follower has a carry capacity, but can pick up anything if you give them an order to pick it up. Some may consider that to be exploiting a glitch.

Also, you can [fast travel while on a horse even when encumbered](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Encumbrance_(Skyrim)#Fast_Travel).

Comment: I was about to post an answer that said much of the same, and also linked to a certain [Penny Acrade comic](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14/thulsa-broom). Only thing I'd add to this answer is that there are ways of [increasing your carry weight](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carry_Weight), and followers like Lydia are *sworn to carry your burdens*.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Those are good points.

Comment: Another point: you can just stuff loot into a container (corpses work, too) near the entrance/exit of a dungeon until you're done exploring. Then, you just take as much as you can carry, fast-travel to the next town, sell the stuff/put it somewhere safe, fast-travel back to dungeon entrance/exit, repeat until the container is empty. Note: make sure you're back inside the dungeon in a certain time limit (IIRC 3 ingame days) or it will reset.

Comment: You said "fast-travel back to dungeon".  If you can go back to where you were, quickly, then that would be a good start.  I thought I had to run all the way back.  An entrance/exit would be ok.

Comment: "Some may consider that to be exploiting a glitch." - Skyrim is a single-player game and Bethesda has quite deliberately left the console and modding utilities readily available.  My interpretation of this is that you should do what you find fun, not what's "fair" or "balanced" (except insofar as a more balanced game is more fun for you personally).

Comment: SkyUI has an option to add a gold-per-weight column to the inventory screen to assist with inventory management.

Comment: Another tip related to potions that increase your carrying weight - you can fast travel even if the potion won't last the entire trip. So if you somehow had a potion that increased your carrying capacity by 1000 for 5 seconds, you could go outside, drink the potion, and immediately fast travel to a city even on the other side of Skyrim.

Comment: @Kevin I agree with that. I usually find exploiting glitches to reduce my fun, so just noting that for anybody who cares.

Comment: I do the 1 weight to 10 gold thing until I come across my first enchanted weapon, then it's straight to soul gems and iron daggers for the rest of the game.

Comment: @Nelson I'll increase the threshold over time. Goes up to 20 at some point, then 50, then 100. It's based on how often I have to stop and drop stuff. I'd prefer not to have to stop and filter more than once a quest.

Comment: @Kevin Well in single player games you can almost certainly avoid the originally designed mechanisms if you want but that in many cases will actually make the game less enjoyable without the player realizing it. e.g. cheating permadeath in roguelike game etc. So one should at least be cautioned to think twice before going through I guess. If the rules are not "fair"/"balanced" anymore, what's the point of challenging the game anyways. The player will lose interest really fast.

Answer (score 3):

One easy trick to go back to town when you are overloaded : **Find a horse**, once you're on it you'll be able to teleport wherever you want ;)

If you own a horse, it will be ( most of the time) waiting for you at the end of the dungeon.

Extra: at the end of some mission in the game that I let you discover, you'll get a spell to conjure a horse just like that which make things way easier :)

Comment: You're saying that you can fast travel on a horse even when encumbered?

Comment: @DCShannon Yes you can, at least on Skyrim Legendary Edition, I'm not sure for the other versions. It's very useful if you want to move a huge amount of things like moving everything to another house, you just go at the gate of the town, conjure Arvak or find your horse and you're good to go

Comment: Cool. +1. I added that to my answer.